# Does Genesis 1:3 describe God creating Jesus Christ?

Tags: exegesis, christology, genesis, denomination-survey

Genesis 1:3 is quite mysterious for Trinitarians, Binitarians, and Unitarians alike. I'm trying to understand what the first work of God was, however, I am finding little to no information on the internet regarding what exactly it (or who) it was that God created.

Do any denominations teach that these verses reveal that God created Jesus on Day 1 of creation?

Genesis 1:3 BSB translation:

> And God said, "**Let there be Light**," **and there was Light**.

John 8:12 BSB translation:

> Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “**I am the Light of the
> world**. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will
> have the light of life.”

Colossians 1:15 ESV translation:

> He is the image of the invisible God, **the firstborn of all creation**.

Proverbs 8:22 translation:

> **YHWH created me at the beginning** of his work, **the first of his acts
> of old**.

Colossians 1:18 translation:

> And He is the head of the body, the church; **He is the beginning and
> the firstborn** from among the dead, so that **in all things He may have
> preeminence**.

Psalm 89:27 translation:

> I will indeed appoint **My firstborn**, as the highest of the kings of the
> earth.

2 Corinthians 4:6 translation:

> For God, who said, “**Let Light shine out of darkness**,” **has made His Light
> shine in our hearts** to give us the light of the knowledge of the glory
> of God **in the face of Jesus Christ**.

John 12:46 translation:

> **I have come into the world as the Light**, so that no one who believes in
> Me should remain in darkness.

John 1:4-5 BSB translation:

> In Him was life, and **that life was the light** of men. **The Light shines
> in the darkness**, and the darkness has not overcome it.

John 1:6-9 BSB translation:

> There came a man who was sent from God. His name was John. He came as
> a witness **to testify about the Light**, so that through him everyone
> might believe. He himself was not the Light, but he came to testify
> about the Light. **The true Light who gives light to every man was
> coming into the world**.

John 3:19 BSB translation:

> And this is the verdict: **The Light has come into the world**, but men
> loved the darkness rather than the Light because their deeds were
> evil.

John 1:1-2 NWT translation:

> **In the beginning was the Word**, and the Word was with God, and **the Word
> was a god**. This one was in the beginning with God.

John 3:18 BLB translation:

> For God so loved the world that He gave **the only begotten Son**, so that
> everyone believing in Him should not perish, but should have eternal
> life.

Proverbs 8:25 BSB translation:

> **Before the mountains were settled**, before the hills, **I was brought
> forth**,

John 17:5 NET translation:

> And now, Father, glorify me at your side with **the glory I had with you
> before the world was created**.

Answer (score 3):

Moderator comments indicated that the Q be aimed at Unitarians; then the OP asked if "Unitarians" could be removed, but the word "Unitarians" was finally lumped by the OP alongside Trinitarians and Binitarians. Therefore, before this Q is closed for apparently refusing to abide by Stack Christianity requirements for Qs, I will give a simple answer.

All the denominations I know of who say God created as his first act of creation the One who later came into the world as the *logos* who became flesh (Jesus Christ), put that before God's creation of a material universe, and before any life appeared anywhere in it. They believe in untold numbers of angelic spirit creatures also being created prior to a physical creation, and most assign the category of a created spirit angel to the *logos*.

The key phrases in Genesis 1 is in verse 1 - "In the beginning, God created..." linked to verse 3, God saying ,"Let there be light. And there was light". It is verse 3 you specifically ask about. The connection between verse 1 and verse 3 is clearly explained centuries later by the apostle John, in the Prologue to his gospel account. This is what clears up the mystery of creation, and God's light, for it says:

> "In ***the beginning*** was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the
> Word was God. The same was in ***the beginning*** with God. All things were
> made by him; and without him was not anything made that was made. In
> him was life, and ***the life was the light of men***. And ***the light shines
> in darkness and the darkness comprehended it not***." John 1:1-4 (emphasis mine) A.V.

It hardly matters what Trinitarians, Binitarians or Unitarians understand regarding the opening verses of Genesis. It's only understanding what the opening verses of John's gospel state in relation to that which clears up any mystery, or misunderstanding. That's because the One who was with God in the beginning, who could never have been made because he made all things that were made, is the source of all God's light to us who walk in darkness.

Comment: I think you're wrong, because Jesus is the "first of his works of old", the "firstborn of creation", the "beginning of the creation of God", and the Light of the world, the first work in Genesis.

Comment: @JoshuaB  If the OP cares to comment to me re. how my answer might be wrong, and improved, I will respond to that, for that is the proper use of comments. This is not a free-for-all-forum that launches into debates or arguments, especially not via comments. That sort of thing is what can get Qs closed down. This site, and Biblical Hermeneutics has already dealt at length with the views in your comments. No group is being 'persecuted' here but any group or individual trying to turn a Q into an argument, a verbal 'boxing match', will attract Moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm "anyone" my answer would be a resounding "NO." All the verses you provided are not saying what you think they mean. I'm not going to go through everyone of them but just high light a few of them.

Starting with John 1:1-3. Genesis 1:1 states, "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth." John 1:1 says, "In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. Both verses start out with the same three words. "In the beginning."

As a side note, technically speaking the definite article has been supplied. The actual Greek is en arche-that is, "in beginning." The main though in Genesis 1:1 is on "WHAT HAPPENED" in the beginning. At John 1:1, the emphasis is on "WHO EXISTED" in the beginning.

In fact John's beginning even "antecedes" the Genesis "beginning, extending without an initial beginning into eternity past, before even time was created. Please note John 17:24, where Jesus, in His humanity, acknowledged that He was with the Father, and loved by the Father, "before the foundation of the world."

What backs this up is also explained at John 1:3, "All things came into being by Him, and apart (or without Him) nothing came into being that has come into being. This is also backed up by Colossians 1:16, Hebrews 1:10, Revelation 3:14, (a verse you forgot to mention where Jesus is identified as the creator and not one that was created.

Revelation 3:14, "The Amen, the faithful and true Witness, the Beginning of the creation of God, says this." The Greek word "arche" is defined as "origin." We get our English word "architect" from that word and what is an architect? He plans and designs and/or facilitate the execution of something. In this case Jesus Christ is the origin of creation. (Some of what I wrote is from the "Institute Of Creation Research").

Comment: Mr. Bond, we meet again. Your answer was unconvincing to me as it panders the illogical Trinitarian fallacy and the bias comes along with it. All I can say is that I missed Revelation 3:14, which is a great verse that very much appears to reinforce the position of my question! This is because Jesus is the beginning of God's creation, the first of his works of old ass the Light!

Comment: @menorahman Yes, we meet again and I can assure you this will not be the last time. What "unconvinces you about my post? And btw, this has nothing to do with the Trinity. What it does have to do with is, "Who is Jesus Christ" as per Matthew 16:13 when Jesus said to His disciples, "Who do people say that the Son of Man is?" How can Jesus not be God when at John 1:3 He is identified as the agent of creation and apart or without Him nothing has come into being that has come into being? This in view of the fact that Isaiah 44:24 says God created everything "All alone and By Himself? Explain this?

Comment: @Mr.Bond - "Who do you say I am"? He replied, "You are the CHRIST, the SON of the LIVING GOD!"

Answer (score 2):

Jesus existed with God before the world was created and that can be seen from the verses in the book of John and Mathew. A **created being** cannot be God because a created being is **not perfect**. Even Lucifer who was an arch angel was not perfect and iniquity was found in him the day he conspired against God's authority in heaven. Jesus qualifies to be God because of

1. The Book of John explicitly says that the word who is Jesus that came into the world was God
   *John 1:1*

> ...and the word was God

It is as literal as the verse above, simplicity is what's needed to understand Biblical metaphor.

Comment: False. Jesus responded by saying, "why do you call me good?  **For nobody is good but God alone**"! And John 1:1c says, "**the Word was a god**", not "the God"!

Comment: Your assertion that our eternally existing perfect creator cannot create a perfect spirit creature is preposterous.

Comment: @Kris, that was before I became a unitarian. Nothing is set in stone because some light is shed on who the prince of your people is

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel   I don’t understand

Comment: @Kris, I used believe in Trinity but now I don't because of some Biblical verses brought to light recently

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel. Oh that’s interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The question if anyone believes X can with great certainty be answered with “yes, probably”. With billions of people on this planet, the chances that anyone believes anything you can think of, are big.

But is there any religion, any variety of christianity that teaches this? It is most certainly not mainstream christianity, as trinitarian belief does not match well with the idea of Jesus being created.

Comment: There was nothing conclusive about your response. I'm still looking for a proper answer that examines the awesome passages that I pulled together, to see what we can find in regards to this fascinating possibility.

Comment: A fascinating possibility? Does anyone believe… probably. Fascinating. But calling something “mysterious” that hardly is mysterious, and asking trinatarians something that is obviously not trinatarian belief, I fail to see the fascinating possibility